# DirecX 11 R8G8B8 24bit format without alpha channel?

Tags: textures, directx, directx11

This is maybe a stupid question but I can't seem to find texture format for simple 24bit R8G8B8? There is only 32bit R8G8B8A8, but some of my textures don't have alpha channel.

Is there any way to do this, or I'll just have to create alpha channel on every texture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8X8_* formats - explicitly no alpha, but still you must expand 24-bit image into 32-bit texture when loading data.
In Direct3D11 24-bit and 16-bit formats are gone for good.

Comment: Note that with DXGI 1.2 (DirectX 11.1 and WDDM 1.2 drivers), 16-bit formats are back: ``DXGI_FORMAT_B5G6R5_UNORM``, ``DXGI_FORMAT_B5G5R5A1_UNORM``, ``DXGI_FORMAT_B4G4R4A4_UNORM``. There are still no 24bpp formats.